# How can I debug a web service used by Infopath?

Tags: c#, infopath

I have an issue of debugging webservice.

How to debug the webservice that is connected with infopath form in my local computer?

now I can only test my webservice by converting it into .wsp package and deploying it into the sharepoint environment but I couldnot debug it.

Comment: How your infopath form talk to web service ? Did you add the service as a secondary data source or you have a code behind for your infopath view ?

Comment: I have the service as a secondary data source. My infopath form is sending the data to webservice that is deployed in the sharepoint server. The main problem for me is to debug webservice or, also may be you can help me to submit data of infopath form to webservice that is located in my computer(means I don't need to deploy it).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links

[Philo's WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philoj/archive/2005/11/08/490200.aspx)

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88547/Submit-entire-InfoPath-form-to-web-service)